# Hyphenator.js not working when class is added with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently looking into hyphenation and due to the lack of `hyphens` support in Chrome and other browsers I decided to use the [Hyphenator.js script](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).

That works all fine but for reason it breaks when I add the `hyphenate` class, to trigger the Hyphenator.js script, with jQuery like below:

```
$(function() {

$( "header.meta h1" ).addClass( "hyphenate" );

});
```

It adds the class to the DOM but somehow prevents the Hyphenator script from doing its job. I really have no clue why. It doesn't matter if I place my jQuery code before or after the Hyphonator script.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like Hyphenator needs to be initialised after adding the class in jQuery - try calling `Hyphenator.run();` after you call `.addClass( "hyphenate")`

You could also refactor this into a function to save repetition, eg:

```
function hyphenate (selector) {
    jQuery(selector).addClass( "hyphenate" );
    Hyphenator.run();
}
```

Comment: Yes it had to be initialised after adding the class. Works fine now, thanks!